# jQuery submit functions

Tags: jquery, form-submit

although I have been coding jQuery for quite some time now, I was just wondering, what is the difference between `$("#test").submit();` and `$("#test).submit(function(e){...});` functions? 
The example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_submit_trigger) doesn't seem to be very clear to me...
Can anyone give any example to show a great use for both of them?

Answer (score 1):

**$("#test").submit()**

This will trigger a submit to #test, if this is a .

**$("#test").submit(function(e) { } )**

This will bind a handler function for *submit event* at form #test.

You can use 1st to submit a form without user interference, for example.

And you can use 2nd to bind a handler function that do something before form submitting, or event disable form submitting by using e.preventDefault().